# Replace character from link with powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I would like replace `?` in

`"EquipmentInfo["?"] = "<iframe src='http://bing.fr'></iframe>";"`

by a variable.

I tried this:

`(get-content C:\word.txt) -replace '?', '$obj' | Set-Content C:\word.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a positive lookbehind to ensure you find the right question mark. Also you have to use **double quote** on your replacement since you want to replace a variable:

```
(get-content C:\word.txt -raw) -replace '(?<=EquipmentInfo\[")\?', "$obj" | Set-Content C:\word.txt
```

Regex used:

```
(?<=EquipmentInfo\[")\?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: ++ for a solid solution: also worth mentioning that a simple variable reference needs no quotes at all.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>*This* answer *explains* the original problem.

[jisaak's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37680208/45375) provides a *comprehensive solution*.</sup>

The `-replace` operator takes a *regular expression* as the first operand on the RHS, in which `?` is a so-called metacharacter with special meaning.

Thus, to use a *literal* `?`, you must *escape* it, using `\`:

```
(get-content C:\word.txt) -replace '\?', $obj
```

<sup>Note: Do not use `'...'` around `$obj`, unless you want *literal* string `$obj`; generally, to reference variables inside strings you must use `"..."`, but that's not necessary here.</sup>

A simple example with a literal:

```
'Right?' -replace '\?', '!' # -> 'Right!'
```

Comment: I try this too but powershell don't agree
+ (get-content C:\word.txt) -replace '?', '$obj' ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : (?:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidRegularExpression

Comment: Then the problem must lie elsewhere - see my example. Please add an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) _directly to your question_.

Comment: Your solution is valid too, thus upvoted. Just wanted to add a more save regex for the replacement. Don't know why he isn't able to run it...

Comment: @jisaak I appreciate it, and I appreciate your comprehensive solution.